# rvm keeps ignoring my .rvmrc

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh, rvmrc

I'm having some problems with my project. I keep an `.rvmrc` in my project's directory with the following config:

`rvm use 1.9.2`

and I put the following lines into my `~/.zshrc`:

```
rvm_project_rvmrc=1
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Yet whenever I `cd` into my project's directory, `ruby -v` shows `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: please add output of `type cd`

Comment: Have you been through all of the zsh integration page?  http://beginrescueend.com/integration/zsh/

Comment: I have the same issue but only when doing `cd .` - zsh doesn't see changes while bash did.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Another thing could be that rvm doesn't trust your rvmrc. Please trust it manually again with

`rvm rvmrc trust DIR`

Answer (score 9):

After an update, RVM seemed to be ignoring all my .rvmrc files.  I eventually got it to work by running

```
rvm reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure rvm is loaded correctly? According to the docs

`type rvm | head -1`

should show

`rvm is a function`

The rvm script referenced in you `~/.zshrc` is only executed if it exists. Otherwise it's skipped silently.

Comment: Thats how it supposed to be. Does the rvm use 1.9.2 command work when executed manually? Is the ruby switched then?

Comment: Another thing could be that rvm doesn't trust your rvmrc. Please try tu trust it manually again with 'rvm rvmrc trust DIR'.

Comment: I added it again as an answer to not hide it in the comments.

Comment: According to the rvm docs, the test string should be `type rvm | head -n 1`

Comment: hmmm... I'm getting `rvm is hashed` instead. Is that something it can also show? Or does that mean there's something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `rvm_project_rvmrc=1` probably only works within your .zshrc, try exporting it to the environment: `export rvm_project_rvmrc=1`

Comment: It's ok now after I applied @iltempo 's suggestion about `rvm` not trusting my `.rmvrc`